# C++: Keep Record of Balance in Bookkeeping Class

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to create a program so that I can keep track of my funds and the people that I owe money to, or plan to spend money on etc.
However I am not sure how to make the computer record my inputs from "cin".
Note: I don't use cin in the program below but I am assuming it would be the same.
At the moment I am in a position where I set the balance of my account and then credit it but the information is not stored. I am hoping that the next time I use the program the balance will be the the final balance of the last input.
Please see my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//Class creation

class account
{ 
public:
   account(float a)
   {
      bal = a;
      std::cout<<"Account made"<<endl;
   }
   void debit(float debit);
   void credit(float credit);
   void printbal(){cout<<"Your Balance is "<<bal<<endl;}
private:
   float bal;
};

//Constructor

void account::debit(float x)
{

  bal = bal + x;
  cout<<"Debiting balance"<<endl;
}

//credit function
void account::credit( float x)
{

  bal = bal - x;
  cout<<"Crediting balance"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  account bank(12);
  bank.account::printbal();
  bank.account::credit(20);
  bank.account::printbal();
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile I get:

```
$./a.out  
Account made  
Your Balance is 12  
Crediting balance  
Your Balance is -8
```

And get the exact same when done again. I am hoping that the second time it will say:

```
Account made  
Your Balance is -8  
Crediting balance  
Your Balance is -28
```

Thank You.

Comment: Unrelated to your bug, but please do not represent Money values as `float`. The bookkeepers will be thankful for that.

Comment: Variables aren't persistent between two runs of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not persistent, you have to store your information in permanent storage.

What you can do is, store the balance in a file or database, every time your program ends. And in the next run, the first thing that you have to do is retrieve the result from the file or DB and perform operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using persistent memory to store the account data.

Everytime that program is executed the same thing happens:

The OS reverse some memory for your program and the `main` function is executed. It creates an account variable with a balance of 12 somewhere within the **reserved memory**. Then the `balance` variable is decreased by `20` and then the program ends.

When the program ends the OS takes back the previously reserved memory. That means that your variable and its content is lost 
 **forever**.

When you run your application again the same thing happen with the OS possibly assigning to your executable a different portion of memory (*with no possibility of writing at the location where the bank variable was stored during the first execution*).

Bottom line is: if you want your data to survive different executions you have to **store on disk or on some other persistent memory** (file, database, cloud, etc.)!